# Phaser - How to access a certain element on the layer

Tags: phaser-framework, tiled

Hello i recently started to study Phaser and i have came to a problem witch i need help with solving. 
I created a 3 layer map with Tiled. SkyLayer, GroundLayer, BrickLayer. I added physics that allow the player to move around the GroundLayer. I also added physics that allow him to jump on the BrickLayer. I am struggling to make a motion that allows the player to jump from the bottom hit the brick with his head, when he hits his head the motion of the brick to move up a pixel and then back down a pixel just as in Mario. I have trouble finding out how to identify which brick section i have hit from the  BrickLayer so i can later on apply the animation to the brick element.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The bricks you can add to a group and implement a collision in the function 'update', with P2JS physics there is an element that is Phaser.Spring, you could add to each brick a spring so that in a collision with the player simulate the Movement of a spring (very similar to Super Mario Bros), another way would be to use physical ARCADE and a timer for each brick ...

Answer (score 0):

Simple Layers itself contains only *tiles*, which has no any animation.

If you need something to have animation, you need to use *object layer* and convert its objects to sprites with [`TileMap.createFromObjects`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Tilemap.html#createFromObjects).